# Firestore - Checking The Connection Status Of The Module To The Server

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have noticed that after turning off the internet connection and than turning it back on (w*hile my `Android` `app` is still running, in the background or not*), it takes the `Firestore` module a pretty long time to regain the connection to the server (about a minute), and I can't make any `Firestore` operations until the connection is regained.

Is this a normal behavior? 
If it does, can I somehow check the `Firestore` module current connection status? (in order to limit my user's actions if there is a need).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no equivalent to Firebase Realtime Database's `.info/connected` in Cloud Firestore, that allows you to verify the connection status. I read on Firebase offical blog a post regarding the [differences between Firebase and Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html) and i saw that this problem is in fact one of the use-cases.

> The Realtime Database has native support for presence -- that is, being able to tell when a user has come online or gone offline. While we do have a solution for Cloud Firestore, it's not quite as elegant.

If you read Firestore [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence), you will see that there is a possible implementation of a presence system by combining Realtime Database and Firestore.

Comment: 'Presence' is a different use case though. It's whether another user has gone offline, while `.info/connection` is relevant only for the current device.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently testing a fix for this that seems to be working.

Step 1: Ensure the device has a data connection using
[Android's recommended approach](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring)

```
public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(@NonNull Context _context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm == null)
        return false;
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Step 2: Force Firestore to connect (the idea is to override Firestore's internal connection retry exponential backoff)

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().enableNetwork()
```

Step 3 (optional): If you're doing this when your app is in the background, you may also want to use Android's Task API to synchronously wait until the enableNetwork() Task completes.  Otherwise, the OS may think your background work is complete, and cut off your app's access to system resources (network, CPU, etc).

```
try { Tasks.await(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().enableNetwork()); }
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error in Firestore enableNetwork(): ", e);
    return;
}
```

Comment: This worked great, I was having issues that our React Native would reconnect to the network but firebase would take 5-15s to reconnect.

I am trying to have this running on a listener that does it automatically when network returns, but it errors out sometimes as:

`FirebaseError: Target ID already exists:` 

Have you seen this one?

Comment: @MorenoMdz I haven't seen that one, but it seems like an error you would get if Firebase is being initialized more than once.  I would start by trying to track down where it get initialized and see if that's getting hit multiple times.