# How can I check the status/health check of my Firestore project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project which uses both the Firestore emulator and an actual firestore database. We're currently trying to explore whether or not we can ping the firestore service to determine if the database is up, in the process of spinning up, or is down.

This should be similar to redis' ping/pong health check.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Firestore is more like a virtual database, it's always up. It's not like a Redis process which can be killed and spun up and has to initialize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore - Checking The Connection Status Of The Module To The Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397547/firestore-checking-the-connection-status-of-the-module-to-the-server)

Comment: Just write a program that makes a query and run it as often as you want to check, using whatever existing service you want that can run jobs periodically.

Comment: What is the use case for doing this kind of check? Per @DougStevenson  suggestion, a query will return an error if it cannot connect to the server as long as the source it set to server. Here's a Swift link [getDocuments(source:completion:)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query.html#getdocumentssource:completion:)

Answer (score 1):

### How to check if Firestore emulator is available

A script can attempt to query Firestore emulator to determine if the service is ready.

#### firestoreHealthCheck.js

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID', // <--- UPDATE 
  databaseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
});

const db = admin.firestore(app);

async function checkFirestoreHealth() {
  try {
    const doc = await db.collection('someRandomCollection').limit(1).get({ source: 'server'});
    console.log('Firestore emulator is ready.');
    process.exit(0); // Exit with success
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to query Firestore.');
    process.exit(1); // Exit with error
  }
}

checkFirestoreHealth();
```

#### Docker compose example

This could be used in Docker compose.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  firebase-emulators:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.emulators
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4000:4000"
      - "127.0.0.1:4400:4400"
      - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
      - "127.0.0.1:5001:5001"
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
      - "127.0.0.1:8085:8085"
      - "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"
      - "127.0.0.1:9099:9099"
      - "127.0.0.1:9199:9199"
      - "127.0.0.1:9299:9299"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "node /home/node/firestoreHealthCheck.js"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/keys/PROJECT_SERVICE_KEY.json
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node
      - $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:/tmp/keys/PROJECT_SERVICE_KEY.json:ro

  node-server:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: apps/node-server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"  # 9090 to avoid conflict with Firestore emulator
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /tmp/keys/PROJECT_SERVICE_KEY.json
      FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST: firebase-emulators:9099
      FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: firebase-emulators:8080
    volumes:
      - ./dist/apps/node-server:/app/node-server
      - $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:/tmp/keys/PROJECT_SERVICE_KEY.json:ro
    depends_on:
      firebase-emulators:
        condition: service_healthy
```